# Не удается инициализировать ссылку

Tags: c++, ссылки

VS пишет что не может инициализировать ссылки (&char, &string) и подчеркивает `fun(s1[1], s1);`

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <climits>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
void display(int n)
{
    cout << n << ' ';
}

typedef unsigned long long          ull;
typedef string                      _type;
typedef vector<_type>               v_t;
typedef vector<vector<_type>>       v2_t;
typedef vector<pair<_type, _type>>  v_p;
typedef vector<bool>                v_b;

v2_t vs(9);

array <char, 1> a0 = { '8' };
array <char, 5> a1 = { '0', '3', '4', '7', '8' };
array <char, 1> a2 = { '8' };
array <char, 2> a3 = { '8', '9' };
array <char, 2> a4 = { '8', '9' };
array <char, 3> a5 = { '6', '8', '9' };
array <char, 1> a6 = { '8' };
array <char, 4> a7 = { '0', '3', '8', '9' };
//array <char, 0> a8;
array <char, 1> a9 = { '8' };

int check(int n)
{
    int k(1);
    for (auto &v1 : vs)
        for(auto &s1 : v1)
        if (atoi(s1.c_str()) <= n)
            ++k;
    return k;
}

void fun(char &ch, string &s)
{
    char old = ch;
    switch (ch)
    {
    case '0':
        for (auto ch1 : a0)
        {
            ch = ch1;
            vs[0].emplace_back(s);
        }
        ch = old;
        break;
    case '1':
        for (auto ch1 : a1)
        {
            ch = ch1;
            vs[1].emplace_back(s);
        }
        ch = old;
        break;
    case '2':
        for (auto ch1 : a2)
        {
            ch = ch1;
            vs[2].emplace_back(s);
        }
        ch = old;
        break;
    case '3':
        for (auto ch1 : a3)
        {
            ch = ch1;
            vs[3].emplace_back(s);
        }
        ch = old;
        break;
    case '4':
        for (auto ch1 : a4)
        {
            ch = ch1;
            vs[4].emplace_back(s);
        }
        ch = old;
        break;
    case '5':
        for (auto ch1 : a5)
        {
            ch = ch1;
            vs[5].emplace_back(s);
        }
        ch = old;
        break;
    case '6':
        for (auto ch1 : a6)
        {
            ch = ch1;
            vs[6].emplace_back(s);
        }
        ch = old;
        break;
    case '7':
        for (auto ch1 : a7)
        {
            ch = ch1;
            vs[7].emplace_back(s);
        }
        ch = old;
        break;
    case '9':
        for (auto ch1 : a9)
        {
            ch = ch1;
            vs[9].emplace_back(s);
        }
        ch = old;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n, sum;
    cin >> n;
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    fun(s[0], s);
    for (auto &s1 : vs)
        fun(s1[1], s1);

    cout << check(n);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `vs` это `vector<vector<string>>`, поэтому в цикле `vs` будет иметь тип `vector<string>`, поэтому `s1` это строка, а функция `fun` первым аргументом принимает символ, так что ошибка компилятора корректна

Comment: @diraria Спасибо, Я не знаю почему я не заметил эту оплошность, просто в предыдущей реализации `vs` был `vector<string>`, поменял и не заметил.

Comment: Не за что) Если не секрет, что это за программа?

Comment: Вы наверное ещё не в курсе, что такое [mcve]. Ознакомьтесь!

Comment: @diraria Она подсчитывает кол-во вариантов того как могли  пропечататься на чеке при наличие n окон (типо как в Macdonalds номер заказа) при условии что аппарат  может что-то недопечатать

Comment: @alexolut Спасибо, я ознакомился с данной статьей, теперь буду знать